# Scheduled Celery Task Lost From Redis

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm using Celery in Django with Redis as the Broker.

Tasks are being scheduled for the future using the eta argument in apply_async.

After scheduling the task, I can run `celery -A MyApp inspect scheduled` and I see the task with the proper eta for the future  (24 hours in the future).

Before the scheduled time, if I restart Redis (with `service redis restart`) or the server reboots, running `celery -A MyApp inspect scheduled` again shows "- empty -".
All scheduled tasks are lost after Redis restarts.

Redis is setup with AOF, so it shouldn't be losing DB state after restarting.

---

### EDIT

After some more research, I found out that running `redis-cli -n 0 hgetall unacked` both before and after the redis restart shows the tasked in the queue. So redis still has knowledge of the task, but for some reason when redis restarts, the task is removed from the worker? And then never sent again and it just stays indefinitely in the unakced queue.